# Setting elements in NSMutableArray to nil

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a NSMutableArray holding a whole bunch of UITextFields which I have created and allocated memory.

In my viewDidUnload method I need to release this memory. How do I do it?

```
for(int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++){
    UITextField* txtField = [arr objectAtIndex i];
    txtField = nil;
}
arr = nil;
```

Will this work? or do I just need to set arr = nil;?

I am using ARC so i set to nil not release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see what your code does to understand what happens:

```
UITextField* txtField = [arr objectAtIndex i];
```

that makes a *copy* of the value in the array, and values in an `NSMutableArray` are references, and stores that value in a variable `txtField`. As `txtField` is defined, implicitly, to hold strong references ARC will (subject to any optimisations) register an ownership interest in the reference (aka "retain"). Your next line:

```
txtField = nil;
```

stores the nil reference value in `txtField`. As `txtField` holds strong references any store causes ARC to relinquish ownership interest (aka "release") in the previous reference value stored in the variable.

The array is never changed. You've iterated over its contents, copied each value, retained that value, released that value. Finally you write:

```
arr = nil;
```

which stores the nil reference value in `arr`. As `arr` holds strong references any store causes ARC to relinquish ownership interest (aka "release") in the previous reference value stored in the variable - and that previous value was your reference to your `NSMutableArray`. If there are no other owners of the array it is destroyed, and when an array is destroyed it relinquishes its ownership of any values it contains - which in this case are your `UITextField` instances, and if there is no other owner of those then they are destroyed...

So at most all you need is:

```
arr = nil
```

but you may not even need that. As `arr` holds strong references when its lifetime ends - at the end of the block or method containing its declaration if a local variable, or when the instance is destroyed if an instance variable - then ARC will relinquish its ownership interest, etc...

HTH

Answer (score 1):

If the array is an instance variable of the view controller, as long as you're using ARC it will automatically be deallocated when the view controller leaves memory.

If you need to manually remove the array, set it to nil.

```
arr = nil;
```

If you need to reuse the array later, you will need to reallocate it after setting it to nil.

Assuming your array is an @property of your object, a good trick is to allocate the array in the getter:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)arr {
    if (!_arr) {
        _arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _arr;
}
```

This way you always get an array when you try to access it, even if it's previously been set to nil.

Comment: The arr is a property of the viewController.
So I don't need to =nil anything I alloc in arc? they will just automatically get freed once the controller leaves memory, so when I change view controllers?

Comment: Correct, that's one of the big benefits of ARC.  In the past, you had to release and dealloc objects.  Now it's done for you.

Comment: Thats brilliant.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: btw - if you change view controllers through navigation, your VC is only removed from memory during a "back" navigation.  A forward navigation keeps your VC in memory.

Comment: Say I was to do this:
[self presentModalViewController:view animated:true]; 
Would that release the controller from memory? or how would I go about releasing it from memory?

Comment: 1) presentModalViewController:animated is depreciated in iOS6.  Use presentViewController:animated:completion:
2) the VC you present will leave memory once you dismiss it.  The presenting VC (the VC that brings up the new VC) will stay in memory after presenting the new VC.  It needs to stay in memory because when you dismiss the new VC, the device will navigate back to the original, presenting VC.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. 
I have a nav that takes me from section to section. So I don't dismiss any. How would I presentViewController and also release the one I am currently on?

Comment: That may lead to poor UI.  If a user is in a nav controller, they expect a back button to return to the previous VC.  If you replace a VC, it may be confusing.  If you wanted to do this, you would send messages to the navigation controller.  First you would send the nav controller -popViewControllerAnimated:, followed by -pushViewController:animated:.

Comment: Ok. That all makes sense. 
Thanks for the advice and answers.

Answer (score 0):

When using ARC, you release a variable by setting it to nil just as you have done with `arr = nil`. Note that the memory will only be freed when all pointers to the object have been set to nil, so make sure you aren't holding on to them anywhere else.

Secondly, if you are running into memory issues you should be handling this in the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method, as viewDidUnload is no longer supported on iOS 6.

Comment: Ok. So from ios 6 I use didReceiveMemoryWarning to release anything instead of viewDidUnload?

Comment: as jb_OH said above, all of the properties of your view controller will be released when the view controller is popped off the navigation stack. you only need to release things manually if you are getting out of memory errors. if you are running out of memory, you should handle releasing objects in didReceiveMemoryWarning. You can do this on both iOS 5 and 6 and I would recommend that for consistency.